# copy var partial bytes in shell

Tags: shell

The following contents in my shell file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

api_params_with_timestamp="somethingXXXX"
SECRET_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" \
        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY")
echo "signature"=$signature
```

execute this shell I got

```
signature=(stdin)= 3eee8d204c83381dddffgggg
```

I just need "3eee8d204c83381dddffgggg" part , what can I do
so that (stdin)= part would be skip ?!

Edit:

```
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" \
        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" | cut -c10-1000)
```

not perfect but works !

Comment: make sure that `openssl` doesn't have an option to turn off exteraneous output (`-q`?). `man openssl`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [openssl-dgst](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-dgst.html) page doesn't provide a direct option to drop the `"(stdin)= "` portion of the output, but that can be done trivially with `cut`, `grep` or `sed`. For example:

**with `cut`**

```bash
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" \
        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" \
        | cut -d ' ' -f2)
```

**with `grep`**

```bash
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" \
        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" \
        | grep -E -o '[^ ]+$')
```

**with `sed`**

```bash
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" \
        | openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" \
        | sed 's/^.*[[:space:]]//')
```

**Note:** you can also remove the line separator characters `"\"` and use the pipe for that purpose instead, e.g.

```bash
signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" |
        openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" |
        sed 's/^.*[[:space:]]//')
```

Either way is fine -- up to you.

**Example Use/Output**

```bash
$ api_params_with_timestamp="somethingXXXX"
> SECRET_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
> signature=$(echo -n "$api_params_with_timestamp" |
>         openssl dgst -sha256 -hmac "$SECRET_KEY" |
>         sed 's/^.*[[:space:]]//')
> echo $signature
46c86ea27df85b8ab9a8c565a344cadd1230f32ff1d773ba0fa5aa1076116d0b
```